# RxJava - ConnectableObservable, disconnecting and reconnecting

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

I am trying to replicate sample code from the "Disconnecting" section [here](https://github.com/Froussios/Intro-To-RxJava/blob/master/Part%203%20-%20Taming%20the%20sequence/6.%20Hot%20and%20Cold%20observables.md).

> Disconnecting
>
> As we saw in connect's signature, this method returns a Subscription, just like Observable.subscribe does. You can use that reference to terminate the ConnectableObservable's subscription. That will stop events from being propagated to observers but it will not unsubscribe them from the ConnectableObservable. **If you call connect again, the ConnectableObservable will start a new subscription and the old observers will begin receiving values again.**

```
ConnectableObservable<Long> connectable = Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish();
Subscription s = connectable.connect();

connectable.subscribe(i -> System.out.println(i));

Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Closing connection");
s.unsubscribe();

Thread.sleep(1000);
System.out.println("Reconnecting");
s = connectable.connect();
```

Output

```
0
1
2
3
4
Closing connection
Reconnecting
0
1
2
...
```

---

Using RxJava 2.0.8, I have:

```
    ConnectableObservable<Long> connectable = Observable.interval(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).publish();
    Disposable s = connectable.connect();

    connectable.subscribe(new Observer<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Long aLong) {
            Log.d("test", "Num: " + aLong);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {

        }
    });

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("test", "Closing connection");
    s.dispose();

    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.d("test", "Reconnecting...");
    connectable.connect();
```

Output

```
Num: 0
Num: 1
Num: 2
Num: 3
Num: 4
Closing connection
Reconnecting...
```

Thanks in advance....

Comment: I 'm not sur to understand your issue

Comment: @Cochi in my code, my subscriber does not receive values after the connectable source has been disconnected, then connected again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems this behaviour has not been adopted by RxJava. The working example is from Rx.NET. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/4771

Comment: Probably yes. The only time I am able to make it work is when I also `subscribe()` again before calling `connect()` again. Is this how it is supposed to work once `dispose()` is called?